# Virtual addressing MMU, where are they stored

Tags: memory-management, arm, microprocessors, mmu

I know there are those 2 types of memory virtual and physical, and MMU mapping between them, but WHAT I can't understand is **WHERE** are stored those virtual addresses if they are "virtual".
Admitting I have 1 process and he has something to read at his virtual address 0x00000004 then the MMU is going to map this virtual address to 0xSomeWhere in the real physical address.
What I want to know is WHERE is this information stored --> 0x00000004 <-- because somewhere there MUST be those bits 00000000000000000000000000000100.

Admitting I have another similar process and he also has an instruction to read at his virtual address 0x00000004, where is this one? How are separated the 2 processes?

Comment: There is a (multi-level) table that is configured by the system before enabling the MMU.  For traditional ARM, the main table entries are 1MB (20 bits) meaning that the table is 32-20=12bits big or 4K*4bytes/entries is 16K (also an alignment constraint).  For finer control, a main entry can point to a 2nd level table with sizes of 1,4,64k.  The configured table is physical (address told to MMU) and each entry/address is virtual with the content in the table telling where the physical is.  Also, a TLB caches this information.

Comment: Lots of information in [tags ARM+MMU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm+mmu?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Comment: the arm documentation describes these tables that artless noise mentioned, the logic walks the table whenever an access happens, it does have a sort of cache to not make that painfully slow.

Comment: I know about TLB, but this virtual address where is it??It must exist somewhere in the universe. I searched in 92862 trilion documentations.

Comment: Which ARM CPU do you want to know about.  Look at [TTBR](https://www.google.ca/search?q=arm+ttbr) references.  For instance, this [slide show on enabling the ARM MMU](https://www.slideshare.net/prabindh/enabling-two-level-translation-tables-in-armv7-mmu) as well as many of the questions here on SO.

Comment: clearly you didnt search any relevant documents because the first two arm documents you need for any arm work one or both covers them. so statements like that are not helpful.  I just deleted the answer I spent time working on as a result.

Comment: *but this virtual address where is it*...  It is any `ldr` or `str` instruction that the CPU issues (from a CPU register value used as an address by code when the MMU is enabled).  The MMU logic will take bit fields and walk the tables as described in links above.  *but this virtual address where is it* is a little bizzare question?  It is any instruction issued to the load/store logic of the CPU (including code lookups; so also the `PC` or program counter).

Comment: If something exist it should be located somewhere in the universe, if this virtual address exist it should be located somewhere in the memory, if it's not the physical memory so WHERE is it? Everybody gives to me the same explanation with a paint of a rectangle at right called physical memory, an MMU and at his left(for example) another rectangle  called virtual memory... in the real world where is stored this left rectangle called virtual memory if it's not the physical one?? If something has an virtual address where is the real silicon and transistors with the bits combination??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The MMU translates/maps the virtual address to a physical address via the selector table.  So, I guess the answer is: the bits are wherever the MMU translates the virtual address to.  If that memory is not available (e.g. swapped to disk) it's generally up to the CPU to fix that, update the MMU, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just like array indexes, virtual addresses are usually<sup>1</sup> not stored anywhere; they're implicit.  The virtual address is used as a index into the page table to look up the physical address.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>It actually depends on the MMU implementation.  Some, such the a PowerPC/Power architecture use a hashing scheme that does involve actually storing virtual addresses in the page table instead of physical addresses</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The virtual addresses are just the addresses in the program image and the CPU registers. User code running on a machine with an MMU doesn't care about the VA-PA mapping, it just has what it believes to be it's own address space. So the PC contains a virtual address, the stack pointer is to a virtual address, etc.

In some sense, it is the PA which is more abstract to the machine. PA is some arbitrary external location, which only the kernel software knows/cares about. (There are other tasks of the mmu, but this covers your question)